# Add configuration file for rcp binary

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I created a `.properties` file in **RCP** application to specify the server address, so that I didn't need to modify the source code when the address is changed.

[image]

This works well when I run **RCP** from the `.product` file, but it didn't work when I exported the RCP to an executable app. I have included the `conf.properties` when exporting the RCP (add to `build.properties` of the feature).

[image]
I can't run the application by double clicking the `.exe` file. I have tried many methods to get the root path of rcp binary but every time it fails. So how to get this configuration file work in binary, or is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```java
URL installURL = Platform.getInstallLocation().getURL();
```

to get a URL for the RCP installation directory.

An alternative is to set properties in the 'xxx.ini' file for your RCP ('console.ini') in your case.

You do this in the .product file editor by adding `-Dpropery=value` values to the 'VM Arguments' section on 'Launching' tab.

Note that during testing these values will not be used, in that case you can set properties in the 'Run Configuration' for the RCP.

Comment: I have tried this, but it returns the location where eclipse installs.

Comment: It will be the location where your RCP installs when you build the RCP, is that not what you want? It looks like the install directory it from the picture.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I only tried this in the IDE. I just tried after exporting the RCP, it works. Thank you very much. One more question, is there a better way to configure the app from the rcp installation? You know in this way I may need two copy of conf.properties, one for eclipse and one for rcp installation.

Comment: you could set properties in the 'console.ini' file in the .product editor - added as an alternative to the answer. You would also have to set these values in the Run Configuration for the RCP during testing.

Comment: You could also just include the properties file in a particular plugin. Using the `FileLocator` class to find it will work in all cases.